# C++: Error: Indirect nonvirtual base class is not allowed

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to create some sort of basic UI in c++ and OpenGL. With this I am using a class called OGLRectangle:

```
class OGLRectangle : public Renderable, public Listener
{
public:
                    OGLRectangle();
                    OGLRectangle(float cX, float cY);
                    ~OGLRectangle();
...
}
```

this is inherited by a Button class that contains shared methods between all button types:

```
 class Button : public OGLRectangle
```

finally the class of ButtonBrowse inherits from this and contains methods for file opening:

```
class ButtonBrowse : public Button
{
    public:
        ButtonBrowse(float cX, float cY);
...
}
```

Now would I be right in saying that to pass the parameters of the constructor in ButtonBrowse I need to do something like this in the constructor:

```
ButtonBrowse::ButtonBrowse(float cX, float cY) : OGLRectangle(cX, cY)
{
...
}
```

and if so why am I getting the indirect nonvirtual error that's in the title?

Comment: I think you need to instead call the constructor for `Button` from `ButtonBrowse` which in turn calls `OGLrectangle`.

Comment: You are getting the error because OGLRectangle is not a direct base of ButtonBrowse. You can only initialize your direct base classes.

Comment: @n.m.: You cannot only initialize direct bases, but also virtual bases.  (That's what the error message is referring to, too.)

Comment: Well a vurtual base is for all practical intents and purposes is a direct base.

Comment: It worked, Thank you!
For some reason I thought that the inheritance chain worked all the way back allowing you to jump steps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call the constructor of `Button`, which will then call the `OGLRectangle` constructor.

```
ButtonBrowse::ButtonBrowse(float cX, float cY) : Button(cX, cY)
{
...
}
```

As long as `Button` has its constructor set up to pass parameters up to its direct base class `OGLRectangle`, you should be fine.

Answer (score -1):

This is not allowed by compiler to pass directly,
You should go step by step and pass these values to base class' constructor destination.